# Using YAML files to store Web Elements of a web Page

Tags: java, selenium, testing, yaml

i am new to software Testing ,i am using selenium(in java ).my question is  how to keep the Web Elements in YAML files and access them  using java right now i am putting them in the  class where i am also putting all the methods which are accessing these elements?

Comment: You want to ask only one question per... question. Otherwise it gets confusing... it's a requirement of the site. Please edit your question and limit it to one question. Please add some more detail to your question and show more of what you have tried and what the result was so we can better understand your scenario and potentially help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you put your WebElements in configuration file in your case YAML(other options are JSON or XML) and build your class and methods around control type.

On how to parse YAML in Java: you can check below link:
http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/

You will find more support packages for parsing JSON or XML.